# Magento 2: Custom value save in sales_order_grid table

Tags: model, order-grid

I have a custom column in the sales_order_grid table and want to save some custom values that are not in **sales_order** table.

Too many tutorials are there that populate sales_order table column into sales_order_grid table via **di.xml** but my requirement is a little bit different. I want to save some other data that is not in sales_order table.

am using observer **sales_model_service_quote_submit_before** and it fire when order place .

Now how can save value in custom attribute in **sales_order_grid** table using model

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?